# The handlebody decomposition of S^1 bundles over surfaces?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, morse-theory, handle-decomposition

What is the most natural handlebody decomposition of $F_g \times S^1$, if $F_g$ is an orientable closed surface of genus $g$?

Answer (score 8):

There is a standard way to get a Heegaard splitting that works more generally for 3-manifolds fibering over $S^1$. Take two copies of the fiber surface, and "tube" them together on either side.

[image]

The two copies of $F_g$ split up the manifold into two copies of $F_g\times I$.

Adding a 1-handle to one  $F_g\times I$ removes a 2-handle from the other side, making it into a handlebody, and hence one gets a Heegaard splitting by removing 2-handles from each piece and adding 1-handles. In this case, this gives the minimal genus Heegaard surface. I can try to dig up a reference if you like.

Comment: I guess in the diagram we want to take $g=k$?

Comment: Yes - I couldn't find a similar picture with $g=k$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? If I "tube" two copies of $F_g$, I get $F_{2g+1}$? Where are the 2-handles glued to? What is the Heegaard genus then of $F_g \times S^1$, is it $2g+1$?

Comment: Just adding a handle to $F_g \times I$ doesn't make a handlebody, you have to remove one as well. Adding a handle won't kill the second homology group, but removing one will. That's why you have to remove one from each copy and add it to the other one.

Comment: Yes, the genus is 2g+1. Clearly this is minimal genus, since it has the fewest generators. I think it is known also that this is the unique minimal genus Heegaard splitting up to isotopy.

Comment: Nice picture.  I dug up the reference for you.  :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct reference here is Schulten's 1993 paper "The classification of Heegaard splittings for (compact orientable surface) $\times S^1$".

https://academic.oup.com/plms/article-abstract/s3-67/2/425/1570629?redirectedFrom=fulltext